# I am not able to check if there is data in variable in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am not able to check if there is any data in a variable in laravel 6 with below function.

```
public function view($slug){

    $userdata = Constant_model::getDataOneColumn('users',"username",$slug);

    if (!empty($userdata)) {

        $data = array(
            'title'=>"User Profile - ",
            'description'=>"profile",
            'seo_keywords'=>'',
            'users'=>$userdata
            );

            return view('view_user_profile',$data); 
         }else{

        $data = array(
            'title'=>"Not found ",
            'description'=>"profile",
            'seo_keywords'=>'',
            'users'=>$userdata
            );
            return view('view_user_profile',$data);
    }


}
```

getDataOneColumn function in Constant_model

```
public static function getDataOneColumn($table, $col1_name, $col1_value){
    $data = DB::table("$table")->where("$col1_name",'=',$col1_value)->get();
      return $data;
  }
```

Getting if data even $userdata has no value. please help

Comment: what is getDataOneColumn ? is it a scope ?

Comment: fetching data from database. fetching data from the model(Constant_model) with function getDataOneColumn

Comment: public static function getDataOneColumn($table, $col1_name, $col1_value){
        $data = DB::table("$table")->where("$col1_name",'=',$col1_value)->get();
          return $data;
      }

Comment: then what is the issue ? there is an error ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 problem is even $userdata variable is empty goes in if statement. but it should go in else statement if $userdata is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking `if (!empty($userdata)) {`
You can check laravel collection like `if ($userdata->isNotEmpty()) {`

```
public function view($slug){

    $userdata = Constant_model::getDataOneColumn('users',"username",$slug);

    if ($userdata->isNotEmpty()) { // Change this line

        $data = array(
            'title'=>"User Profile - ",
            'description'=>"profile",
            'seo_keywords'=>'',
            'users'=>$userdata
            );

            return view('view_user_profile',$data); 
         }else{

        $data = array(
            'title'=>"Not found ",
            'description'=>"profile",
            'seo_keywords'=>'',
            'users'=>$userdata
            );
            return view('view_user_profile',$data);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `count`:

```
if ($userdata->count() > 0) {
```

Comment: it works! but i was using simply if($userdata){ } in codeignter it was perfectly working...is it due to php version?

Comment: @UpasanaChauhan no it is not a PHP version thing. It is because `get()` is returning an *empty collection* - which is not technically empty. You can use `->count()` or `->isEmpty()` / `isNotEmpty()`.

Comment: I think it's because of Laravel behaviour.